# Why are some chatty, open-ended questions not closed?

Tags: discussion

> What are the most common mistakes that beginners of C# make?

Very open-ended question, right? I am absolutely sure that the above question will be closed instantly with so many downvotes if asked on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Then, why are some questions like "[What are the most common mistakes that beginners of (La)TeX and Friends make?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139873/7628)" treated differently and allowed on SE while they are clearly among the [list of questions that should not be asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be posted on http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Each site will come to its own precise rules on what is on-topic and acceptable. If you want to know why it's still open, go ask them. Perhaps it should be closed, but not enough people with the appropriate moderating power have seen it.

Comment: Different communities have different expectations as to what is acceptable on their sites and what isn't.  Remember that SO is much larger than Tex.SE - once upon a time we allowed these sorts of questions as well.

Comment: @Bart Read these two pages, they have prohibited pretty much the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Read these two pages, they have prohibited pretty much the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Well, then you should ask on their Meta.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be asked on http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Reopening because, in the words of the flagger who requested it, this post "is a useful reference about SE-in-general even if the _answer to it_ is 'see the site meta.'"

Comment: I smell recursion enforcement under way.

Answer (score 1):

[The question you linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139873/7628) may be open for a number of reasons:

- Nobody's closed it yet, maybe because everyone thinking of closing it sees there's no close votes on it and wonders if there's a good reason it's still open, and.
- It's slipped through the cracks.
- This is one of those borderline cases that particular SE site accepts. Some sites accept, say, product identification questions, even though they are not necessarily good questions.

It's also worth bearing in mind that each Stack Exchange site evolves its own standards for questions and answers, though all generally adhere to the common principles found in the Help pages.

**This is a case for that community's meta, not Meta Stack Overflow.** You should bring this up on the [TEX meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/) and ask the users on *that site* why it's still open, and propose its closure, if you think it should be closed. They can then discuss it with regards to *their* standards of what makes for a good question. If there's a good or historic reason the question is still open (point 1), it will surface (and could be challenged). If there isn't one, the users may decide to close it.